# Sorting Multidimensional Array of Objects for Both Numbers and Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

```
var customers = [
  {'Name' : 'John', 'Attributes' : {'Age' : 5, 'Height' : 1.5, 'Country': 'USA', 'Clothes' : {'Shirts' : 5, 'Pants' : 8}}}, 
  {'Name' : 'Andrew', 'Attributes' : {'Age' : 9, 'Height' : 1.8, 'Country': 'Canada', 'Clothes' : {'Shirts' : 2, 'Pants' : 5}}}, 
  {'Name' : 'Lucifer', 'Attributes' : {'Age' : 11, 'Height' : 1.3, 'Country': 'France', 'Clothes' : {'Shirts' : 9, 'Pants' : 4}}}
];

function sort(valuePath, array){
  let path = valuePath.split('.')  

  return array.sort((a, b) => {
     return getValue(b,path) -  getValue(a,path)    
  });

  function getValue(obj, path){
    path.forEach(path => obj = obj[path])
    return obj;
  }
}
```

I have this working structure of functions if I trigger:

```
sort('Attributes.Height', customers)
```

But if I choose to work with text, it's not working e.g.:

```
sort('Attributes.Country', customers)
```

How may I apply the necessary modification? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting on string works differently, read it from [here](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort). Idea would be to first detect what is the type of key on which you are applying sort either a number or string and then apply sort accordingly.

```js
var customers = [ {'Name' : 'Andrew', 'Attributes' : {'Age' : 9, 'Height' : 1.8, 'Country': 'Canada', 'Clothes' : {'Shirts' : 2, 'Pants' : 5}}}, {'Name' : 'John', 'Attributes' : {'Age' : 5, 'Height' : 1.5, 'Country': 'USA', 'Clothes' : {'Shirts' : 5, 'Pants' : 8}}}, {'Name' : 'Lucifer', 'Attributes' : {'Age' : 11, 'Height' : 1.3, 'Country': 'France', 'Clothes' : {'Shirts' : 9, 'Pants' : 4}}}];

function sort(valuePath, array){
  let path = valuePath.split('.')  
  let value = getType(array[0],path);
  
  if(value == 'string'){
     return array.sort((a, b) => (getValue(a,path).toUpperCase() > getValue(b,path).toUpperCase()) - (getValue(a,path).toUpperCase() < getValue(b,path).toUpperCase()))
  } else {
     return array.sort((a, b) => getValue(a,path) -  getValue(b,path));
  }
 
 function getValue(obj, path){
    path.forEach(path => obj = obj[path])
    return obj;
  }
 
  function getType(obj, path){
    path.forEach(path => obj = obj[path])
    return typeof obj;
  }
}

console.log(sort('Attributes.Country', customers));
console.log(sort('Attributes.Height', customers));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a mathematical comparison using the minus operator, you can just compare the values with `<` and `>` operators. This will work for both numbers and strings.

```
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
     if (getValue(a,path) < getValue(b,path)) {
       return -1;
     }
     if (getValue(a,path) > getValue(b,path)) {
       return 1;
     }
     return 0;
  });
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

Answer (score 1):

You could take a sorting appraoch which works with numbers and characters and use a closure over path and sorting order.

This approach uses a changed order of parameters by having the array as first parameter.

```js
const
    sort = (array, valuePath, order = 'ASC') => {
        const
            getValue =
                (path => object => path.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object))
                (valuePath.split('.')),
            asc = order === 'ASC' || -1;

        return array.sort((a, b) => {
            const
                aa = getValue(a),
                bb = getValue(b);

            return asc * ((aa > bb) || -(aa < bb));
        });
    };

var customers = [{ Name: "John", Attributes: { Age: 5, Height: 1.5, Country: "USA", Clothes: { Shirts: 5, Pants: 8 } } }, { Name: "Andrew", Attributes: { Age: 9, Height: 1.8, Country: "Canada", Clothes: { Shirts: 2, Pants: 5 } } }, { Name: "Lucifer", Attributes: { Age: 11, Height: 1.3, Country: "France", Clothes: { Shirts: 9, Pants: 4 } } }];


console.log(sort(customers, 'Attributes.Height', 'DESC'));
console.log(sort(customers, 'Attributes.Country', 'DESC'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Here is a spread problem for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840455/comparing-two-arrays-and-adding-objects-to-the-other-one