# Comparing two arrays and adding objects to the other one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays:

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    _id: '5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35',
    name: 'Strawberry',
    category: 'organic',
    image: '/productImages/australian.jpg',
    price: '9.65',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    _id: '5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36',
    name: 'Organic Wild Blue Berry',
    category: 'organic',
    image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg',
    price: '12.50',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    _id: '5eb0ac47d98c817d9a82df82',
    name: 'Mango',
    category: 'australian',
    image: '/productImages/australian.jpg',
    price: '12.25',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    _id: '5eb0ac71d98c817d9a82df83',
    name: 'Peas',
    category: 'conventional',
    image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg',
    price: '25.12',
    quantity: 1
  }
]

let array2 = [
  {
    _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a557',
    productid: {
      _id: '5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35',
      name: 'Strawberry',
      category: 'organic',
      image: '/productImages/australian.jpg',
      price: '9.65'
    },
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a558',
    productid: {
      _id: '5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36',
      name: 'Organic Wild Blue Berry',
      category: 'organic',
      image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg',
      price: '12.50'
    },
    quantity: 3
  }
]
```

I need to check if `productId` of `array2` matches any object `_id` of `array1`. If so, I need to add each object's quantities to one another. Otherwise, I need to push one to another.

For example, if  `"_id": "5eb0ac71d98c817d9a82df83"` doesn't exist in any object of `array2`'s `productId`, push it into `array2`. And if any element of `array2` doesn't exist in `array1`, push it into `array1`.

I managed to update the quantity if one of the objects included in the other array but can't figure out a way to push the rest of the objects to one another.

Here is how I combined the quantities of matching `_id` from `array1` to `productId` in `array2`

```js
if (array1.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < array1.length; k++) {
      if (array2[i].productid._id === array1[k]._id) {
        array1[k].quantity = array1[k].quantity + array2[i].quantity
        array2[i].quantity = array1[k].quantity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result based on example above:

```js
array1 = [
  {
    _id: '5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35',
    name: 'Strawberry',
    category: 'organic',
    image: '/productImages/australian.jpg',
    price: '9.65',
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    _id: '5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36',
    name: 'Organic Wild Blue Berry',
    category: 'organic',
    image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg',
    price: '12.50',
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    _id: '5eb0ac47d98c817d9a82df82',
    name: 'Mango',
    category: 'australian',
    image: '/productImages/australian.jpg',
    price: '12.25',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    _id: '5eb0ac71d98c817d9a82df83',
    name: 'Peas',
    category: 'conventional',
    image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg',
    price: '25.12',
    quantity: 1
  }
]

array2 = [
  {
    _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a557',
    productid: {
      _id: '5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35',
      name: 'Strawberry',
      category: 'organic',
      image: '/productImages/australian.jpg',
      price: '9.65'
    },
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a558',
    productid: {
      _id: '5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36',
      name: 'Organic Wild Blue Berry',
      category: 'organic',
      image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg',
      price: '12.50'
    },
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    _id: 'auto-generated-id',
    productid: {
      _id: '5eb0ac47d98c817d9a82df82',
      name: 'Mango',
      category: 'australian',
      image: '/productImages/australian.jpg',
      price: '12.25'
    },
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 'auto-generated-id',
    productid: {
      _id: '5eb0ac71d98c817d9a82df83',
      name: 'Peas',
      category: 'conventional',
      image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg',
      price: '25.12'
    },
    quantity: 1
  }
]
```

Comment: I think @NinaScholz needs to do her spread magic ;)

Comment: I would def appreciate that @NinaScholz

Comment: Why do you need two arrays at the end if they are equal?

Comment: second array comes from db, i need to update the localstorage and db with both combined @JonasWilms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce` function. Here is my try:

```js
var array1 =[{"_id":"5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35","name":"Strawberry","category":"organic","image":"/productImages/australian.jpg","price":"9.65","quantity":1},{"_id":"5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36","name":"Organic Wild Blue Berry","category":"organic","image":"/productImages/owbb.jpg","price":"12.50","quantity":1},{"_id":"5eb0ac47d98c817d9a82df82","name":"Mango","category":"australian","image":"/productImages/australian.jpg","price":"12.25","quantity":1},{"_id":"5eb0ac71d98c817d9a82df83","name":"Peas","category":"conventional","image":"/productImages/owbb.jpg","price":"25.12","quantity":1}];

var array2=[ { _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a557', productid: { _id: '5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35', name: 'Strawberry', category: 'organic', image: '/productImages/australian.jpg', price: '9.65', }, quantity: 3 }, { _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a558', productid: { _id: '5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36', name: 'Organic Wild Blue Berry', category: 'organic', image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg', price: '12.50', }, quantity: 3 }];


result = array1.reduce((acc, elem, i)=>{
    index = array2.findIndex(val=>val.productid._id == elem._id);
 if(index!=-1) {
  array2[index].quantity = elem.quantity += array2[index].quantity;
 } else {
   array2.push({_id:'some_id'+i, productid: elem, quantity: elem.quantity})
 }
    acc.push(elem);
 return acc;
},[]);

result = [...result, ...array2.filter(elem=> !array1.some(val=>val._id == elem.productid._id)).map(({productid, quantity})=>({...productid, quantity}))];


console.log(result);
console.log(array2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @ertemishakk I'm glad it helped.

Comment: how can I add the option to check if array1 is empty or doesnt have any object from array2 and if so push array2 objects into array1 just like the one above or vice versa. Just realized it doesnt work when the array1 is empty/or doesnt have any objects from array2.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, one more thing, you filter and map the objects that exists in array2 and push it into array1, everything works good, except when you do that, you forget the quantity, can you update it one more time for me. Thank you!

Comment: @ertemishakk Updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been working on it for whole day. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would add the quantities of the first array to the second, then regenerate the second array based on the first:

```
  // Create a lookup table to make the whole thing O(n)
  const entryById = {};
  for(const item of array2)
    entryById[item.productid._id] = item;

  // Update array2 with the amount of array1
  for(const item of array1) {
    if(entryById[item]) {
       entryById[item].amount += item.amount;
    } else {
       array2.push(entryById[item] = {
         _id: 'generated',
         productid: item,
         amount: item.amount,
      });
    }
  }

 // Regenerate array1
 array1 = array2.map(({ productid, amount }) => ({ ...productid, amount }));
```

I find it strange though that you maintain two different datastructures here.

Comment: Thank you very much. mongodb generates _id's for eact items that I add into array2 besides the productid.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for the second array and iterate the first and push a new data set and update the values.

```js
let array1 = [{ _id: "5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35", name: "Strawberry", category: "organic", image: "/productImages/australian.jpg", price: "9.65", quantity: 1 }, { _id: "5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36", name: "Organic Wild Blue Berry", category: "organic", image: "/productImages/owbb.jpg", price: "12.50", quantity: 1 }, { _id: "5eb0ac47d98c817d9a82df82", name: "Mango", category: "australian", image: "/productImages/australian.jpg", price: "12.25", quantity: 1 }, { _id: "5eb0ac71d98c817d9a82df83", name: "Peas", category: "conventional", image: "/productImages/owbb.jpg", price: "25.12", quantity: 1 }],
    array2 = [{ _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a557', productid: { _id: '5eaf8eeac436dbc9b7d75f35', name: 'Strawberry', category: 'organic', image: '/productImages/australian.jpg', price: '9.65', }, quantity: 3 }, { _id: '5ec00539f7ff70566fd8a558', productid: { _id: '5eaf8f61c436dbc9b7d75f36', name: 'Organic Wild Blue Berry', category: 'organic', image: '/productImages/owbb.jpg', price: '12.50', }, quantity: 3 }],
    ids = array2.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.productid._id] = o; return r;
    }, {}),
    result = array1.forEach(o => {
        if (ids[o._id]) {
            const value = o.quantity;
            o.quantity += ids[o._id].quantity;
            ids[o._id].quantity += value;
        } else {
            const { quantity, ...productid } = o;
            array2.push(ids[productid._id] = { _id: 'auto-generated-id', productid, quantity });
        }
    });

   console.log(array1);
   console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```